# Writing a Pseudocode for algorithm to determine the category in which the attendee falls

Tags: algorithm

How to write the pseudocode for this question? I tried writing the algorithm instead but it's really hard.

An algorithm or Pseudocode that accepts as input the names of 22 persons attending a conference. Each person falls under one of two categories:
a)Participant
b)Presenter

The algorithm should determine the category in which the attendee falls. The algorithm should also determine the number of attendees who fall under each category. A participant pays a registration fee of $2000.00 and a presenter $1000.00. A listing of category and the total number of persons in each category must be printed, along with the total amount of money generated in each section.

This is what I've tried but no luck.

```pascal
program Persons attending the conference (input,output);
Uses Crt

Const
    Presenters=('per17,per18,per19,per20,per21,per22'),'('$1000.00);
    Participant=('per1,per2,per3,per4,per5,per6,per7,per8,per9,per10,per11,per12,per13,per14,per15,per16'),'('$2000.00);


begin
    {Accept the names of 22 persons and category}
    WriteLn ('Enter names');
    ReadLn ('per1,per2,per3,per4,per5,per6,per7,per8,per9,per10,per11,per12,per13,per14,per15,per16,per17,per18,per19,per20,per21,per22');
    WriteLn ('Enter Category')
    Var
      participant:('per1...per16');
      presenter: ('per17...per22');
end.
```

Comment: Pseudo-code = programming in english. One does not simply convert to pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come from a [python](/questions/tagged/python) background. I will show you each line of "code" and explain my rational behind it.

```
Participants = 0
Presenter = 0
```

Here I created two integer variables, `Participants` and `Presenters`. These will hold the number of people in each variable.

```
for x in range (22):
    ask if person is presenter or participant
```

This code makes the program ask the user if the person is a presenter or participant. This is repeated 22 times.

```
    if presenter:
        Presenter += 1
    if participant:
        Participants += 1
```

This code checks to see what group the newest person falls into. It then adds 1 to that variable.

```
print "There are", Participants, "participants."
print "There are", Presenter, "presenters."
```

This code tells us how many are in each group.

```
print "You earned", (Participants * 2000) , " dollars from participants."
print "You earned", (Presenter * 1000), "dollars from presenters."
print "Overall, you earned", (Presenter * 1000) + (Participants * 2000), "dollars."
```

This code displays the output on the screen.

**NOTE:** Next time you ask a question on SO, you should tell us

1. What language you are using.
2. What you have tried so far. (You did this, but it is better to use an actual language.)
3. A *specific* question. Tell us *exactly* what you need, not "Please help!!!"

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm actually using pascal language,I needed to know how the question would be represented in the programming language pascal.

Comment: @user2133181 Thanks! If you have any more questions, go to chat and ask for my help by doing .@xxmbabanexx (ignore the period) and then your message or link to your question.

Comment: @xxmbabanexx Please don't ask people to accept/up vote your posts. Thanks!